# Git: How to make submodule pointer point to identical commit on two parent branches

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, git-submodules

I have a project `parent` with branches `master` and `work`. The `master` branch is solely used to pull changes from an upstream repository and from time to time merge these changes into the `work` branch. No changes will be done to the master branch.

The project has a submodule `child`. At some point, after I merged changes from the `master` branch to the `work` branch, I noticed that the submodule pointers on the two branches differ. Whenever I switch from one branch to the other and then type `git status`, I get, e.g. when switching back to `master`:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   child (new commits)
```

And the output for `git diff` is something along the lines of:

```
diff --git a/child b/child
index 02232f9..5902a22 160000
--- a/child
+++ b/child
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit abcdefdeadbeef0123456789
+Subproject commit 12381257dea0ffff018dead
```

Updating the submodule via `git submodule update` "fixes" the immediate issue by making the change go away, but whenever I switch branches I will have a tainted index again. I want the submodule pointer of branch `work` to always point to the same commit as the one on branch `master` did when I last merged `master` into `work`, but after executing `git submodule update`, I can't merge `master` into `work`, because git thinks that `work` is already up-to-date.

**How can I "repair" the submodule pointer in branch `work` and make it point to the same commit as the one in branch `master` does?**

I know that there was a conflict issue once in the past with the submodule on branch `work`, but I don't know anymore when and where it happened and therefore I can't really tell why exactly this situation occurred.

**Is there a way to find out which commit to `parent` changed the submodule pointer?** According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37064338/whats-the-git-command-to-determine-which-commit-changed-a-submodule-pointer), it's not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to commit the updated sub-module just like you would a code change. After getting the submodule to the commit that you want it, from the root of the main project while in the branch you want to update (in your case `work`):

```
git add .
git commit -m "Updating Submodule"
```

That will make your branch "point" at the correct commit.

Alternatively, if you have other changes that you don't want to commit

```
git add /path/to/module
git commit -m "Updating Submodule"
```

Comment: This solved the problem when done on the `work` branch! It would be nice if you could clarify your answer, i.e. on branch `work`, you have to manually update the submodule to the specific commit you want it to be at and *then* add that change to the index!

Comment: I added some clarification.  I left it more general for posterity sake since `git commit` always affects the branch you're currently on and sometimes someone might want to update a sub-module on a different branch.